# Write int structure data type to file in c

Tags: c, arrays, struct, int, printf

A bit of background to my program. I'm asking the user to input coordinates for two different colour crystals. This will be held in a structure and then written to file, to be read back later by the program (function yet to be written).

I have had a look on forums and blogs but I seem to be only finding results relating to character arrays, whereas I am using an int array.

My code works fine until the writing of the data to the file. (this is the snippet of code)

```
char fname[20];
FILE *fp;
int loop;
struct coord{
int x;
int y;
    };

for(loop=0;loop<3;loop++){
printf("Enter MAGENTA X coordinate: \n");
    scanf("%2d",&mg[loop].x);
printf("Enter MAGENTA Y coordinate: \n");
    scanf("%2d",&mg[loop].y);
    printf("\n\n");
}

for(loop=0;loop<3;loop++){
printf("Enter YELLOW X coordinate: \n");
    scanf("%2d",&ylw[loop].x);
printf("Enter YELLOW Y coordinate: \n");
    scanf("%2d",&ylw[loop].y);
    printf("\n\n");
}

clrscr();

printf("\nDetail entered:");
printf("\n\n\tMagenta\t\tYellow\n");
for(loop=0;loop<3;loop++){
    printf("\tx %d,%d y\tx %d,%d y\n",mg[loop].x,mg[loop].y,ylw[loop].x,mg[loop].y);
}

printf("\n\nPlease save your data. Enter file name: ");
gets(fname);
fp=fopen(fname,"w");

for(loop=0;loop<3;loop++){
    fprintf(fp,"%d,%d ",mg[loop].x,mg[loop].y);
    fprintf(fp,"%d,%d ",ylw[loop].x,ylw[loop].y);
}

fclose(fp);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `My code works fine until the writing of the data to the file` ... and *then* what happens?

Comment: What is the format of the input? Can you give an example?

Comment: @RobertHarvey my compiler gives the error Expression: (str != NULL)

Comment: @TylerDurden Input is type int. a range of value from 0-50 for x and 0-100 for y. IT's a grid sort of representation.

Comment: @j_prog: The compiler error doesn't have to do anything with the code you showed. Where's `str`?

Comment: @MOehm I don't have 'str' in my code as a variable. Perhaps having an if statement to store a NULL pointer?

Comment: I've added in flush(stdin) just before the prompt to enter a filename. It seemed to work. Would there be any other options?

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` causes undefined behaviour, don't use it.  To get better help, please post code that actually compiles without any changes. We don't have a crystal ball.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with how you write the data to the file (maybe except that you should check the return value of `fopen`.)

Your problems are in the input of your data from `stdin`. First, your read in a bunch of coordinates with `scanf`. `scanf` is not a line-based format; it treats a new-line character like any other white-space.

Then you use `gets`, which you really shouldn't - use `fgets` instead, because it allows you to specify a maximum buffer size so that you don't overflow your buffer of 20.

Okay, say you use `fgets`, which is a line-based format. You have to take care when mixing `scanf` and `fgets`, because they work differently. Also input from the console is usually buffered until the next newline, when it is all flushed, which can create a discrepancy between what you see on the screen and how the program processes input.

Say you read two numbers with `scanf` and then a filename with `fgets`. Your input looks like this:

```
1  2  \n  5  1  \n  d  a  t  a  .  t  x  t
a  a  b   b  b  c
```

After reading the first number the input marker is after the number, before the newline. `scanf` skips white space before numbners read with `"%d"`, so the second number is read in, but again, input stops before the newline. Then you read a line with `fgets` and read everything up to the next newline, which is nothing. The real filename would be read by the next scanning function, but there isn't any, so it's discarded.

(That's where your `str != NULL is coming from: it's an assertion that has failed within`fopen`. This is nopt something that the *compiler* does, though. When you run the program, it has already been compiled. The run-time library does such error checking of conditions it can't know at compile time.)

(What's worse: `fgets`, unlike `gets`, retains the newline after the read string. You shoud remove that and possibly other leading and trailing white-space, too. Otherwise you'll end up with a file name that has a new-line in it, which is not funny.)

Anyway, how can you fix this? Change your `scanf` formats from `"%d"` to `"%d "` with a trailing space. "Space" has a meaning to `scanf`: read any amount of white space.

Alternatively, you could stick to `scanf` and read your filname with `scanf("%19s ", filename)`. That has the benefit of reading a string without any whitespace in it.

Reportedly you have fixed this by calling `fflush(stdin)` before reading the filename. The behaviour of `fflush` on input streams is implementation-dependent and not guaranteed by the standard. If it worked for you, leave it at that.

Comment: Very thorough explanation! Wouldn't formatting the fprintf like this solve such an issue also?        fprintf(fp,"%d,%d ",mg[loop].x,mg[loop].y);

Comment: No, that's output - something else entirely. A space in `fprintf` means: write one space. I'm not a big fan of reading input interactively from `stdin` with `scanf`. For example if the program asks for the first value, the user could write "2 3", thereby entering two values, the second of which will be read from a `scanf` that is performed after another promt is written - after the input value. From now on, your prompts and data are out of sync. (Btw, the explanation is only thorough, because the matter is so complicated. All the input stuff is far more complex than your real problem at hand.)